# Disable Hyperlink on a SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I want to disable the hyperlink for a specific class part of Site Feeds in SharePoint 2013.

I`m using Jquery to do the same, but it is not working for me.
Code for reference

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



 var location= $('.ms-microfeed-userName ms-textLarge ms-subtleLink').attr("href");
 $(".ms-microfeed-userName ms-textLarge ms-subtleLink").removeAttr('href');
 $('ul').addClass('expanded');
 $('ul.expanded').fadeIn(300);
 $(".ms-microfeed-userName ms-textLarge ms-subtleLink").attr("href", location);


 </script>
```

Comment: The code seems to not at all remove a hyperlink, you should really just need the second jQuery line, but with my alterations from the answer below

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake when you're selecting the elements using multiple classes.  It should be like this

```
$('.ms-microfeed-userName, .ms-textLarge, .ms-subtleLink').attr("href");
```

Instead of `$('.ms-microfeed-userName ms-textLarge ms-subtleLink').attr("href");`

Comment: That's also wrong, it should be `$('.ms-microfeed-userName.ms-textLarge.ms-subtleLink')` since the ancor tag has al three classes on it

Comment: @Robert, I tried with both options:

code 1:
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.ms-microfeed-userName.ms-textLarge.ms-subtleLink').click(function () {return false;}); 
  
 
 </script>


Code 2:

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.ms-microfeed-userName.ms-textLarge.ms-subtleLink').attr("href"); 
  
 
 </script>

Still the same

Comment: @robert howz that supposed to work, how will jquery understand if the classes are not separated..  Jason did you try my solution

Comment: @ThatThatGuy are you serious? The element in question is ONE a-tag with three classes on it, so the pattern I gave is how you select it in CSS and hence in jQUery selector

Comment: @jason do check if you're able to select the elements with multiple classes

Comment: @robert ive checked both of our solutions they work fine

Comment: Sure they do, but yours would potentially modify all elements having the `.ms-textLarge` or `.ms-subtleLink` classes only

Comment: please check if my code is correct -

'code'

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 
$('.ms-microfeed-userName.ms-textLarge.ms-subtleLink').click (function () {

return false; 
});
});

 
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
 
$('.ms-vb').click (function () {

return false; 
});
});
  
 
 </script>

'code'

Comment: @Robert Further update, I have another script that allows to remove the hyperlink on all a href items that are part of class= ms-vb.

code

 <script>
 
 $(function() {
 
$('.ms-vb').removeAttr("href");
// disable all links in a document
$('a').removeAttr("href"); 

});

</script>

code

still its not working as expected.

I`m using a content editor webpart in SharePoint and adding the script exactly as shown above. Please suggest if I`m missing something.

Comment: Guys pls assist. I m able to get it working for most of the class. But its not working for the class associated with site column name Modified. Tried checking via ie dev tool if i need to add any other class.  Any suggestions.